# How does village border growth work in Reus?

Tags: reus

What are the factors that control when and how the border posts move?

I've read a couple of theories, and made some observations, but it's still pretty unclear to me. I saw a number of ideas floating around on the internet, and did some pseudo-exact experiments of my own; I'll put some of those up as food for discussion later.

Comment: I say it is bound to the prosperity, but the wiki does not say anything about it. http://wiki.reusgame.com/

Comment: This forum post should answer that question: [http://forums.abbeygames.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=781](http://forums.abbeygames.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=781)

Comment: @Rachel: I wrote that :-) Thanks for reminding me to update my answer (to make it more self-contained)!

Answer (score 5):

The first I did experiment was digging an ocean, planting a forest, putting down a fruit tree and then waiting. After the settlement, I marked the borders by putting down a Reus and then regularly checking to see if they'd expanded. They did, with an interval somewhere between 3 and 4 minutes, with no apparent bias to left versus right. This was on a 30-minute world.

Anecdotal evidence, because I still have to try the following varying factors:

- Longer world. I feel the rate should slow down for 120-minute worlds, but I haven't tried that yet.
- Neighbouring biomes: does it take longer to go into the ocean, say?
- Local availabilty of prosperity: does a village with two food grow faster or slower than a village with 80 excess food? That could be tested with some extra elder/strawberry combos.
- Total availabilty of prosperity: does it make a difference if a village half the world over has way too many resources?

Comment: If it's slower in a 120 minute world, it's not by a lot; I keep moving to focus on another village only to find that by the time I check on the first one, it's doubled in size.

Comment: @Yamikuronue You're right, it doesn't matter. I should update my answer here with the information I found out in http://forums.abbeygames.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=781 (and I should update *that* answer to 1.1.2!)

Comment: Yesterday I had a situation where I had a village with a lot of danger not grow for quite some time -- something like 20 minutes. I had been ignoring them, so it might be that they capped out their prosperity, or the danger might have mitigated it, but neither factor is mentioned in this answer

Comment: `Neighbouring biomes: does it take longer to go into the ocean, say?`

I saw a post somewhere by one of the guys who worked on the game saying that it does expand slower into oceans, though he didn't mention any of the other biomes

Answer (score 5):

> A village has so-called 'reach points', these get increased every 5
>   seconds by 0.025 points (so a full point every 200 seconds). Also
>   every 5 seconds, a village checks to see whether it can expand its
>   borders. Each new tile has a buy cost, and if a village has enough
>   reach points, it gets the tile (with a slight preference for expanding
>   to the left - but I'm sure which that direction that actually is!). If
>   it can't afford either tile, it just keeps accumulating reach points,
>   so that when a bottled up village has one of it's neighbours
>   destroyed, it can expand quickly.

[Source](http://forums.abbeygames.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=781)

Comment: +1 for quoting the relevant part, as the source URL is now 404